# One label two input fields?

Tags: html, label

I am working on a form that is in a format like:

```
               HOME                 CELL
PHONE_NUM      TEXT_INPUT           TEXT_INPUT2
```

Why can't TEXT_INPUT and TEXT_INPUT2 be listed in the for with &&?

The benifit of having the label is to keep the input fields aligned correctly on the same row.. is there any other benifit?

Comment: Show your actual HTML please

Comment: You have misundestood what the `label` element means (it has no effect like the one you imagine), and hence there is hardly any feasible interpretation for the question. Try showing your markup, explaining what you expect it to do, and what specific problem you are having with it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `for` attribute to a label makes it so clicking on the label will put focus on the input (assuming it's a text input). Therefore having two `id`s in a single `for` attribute doesn't make sense: the browser wouldn't know which input to put focus on.

`for` attributes also have nothing to do with styling and positioning. You should be able to keep your form looking the same without a `for` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

**There ARE other benefits** - The `<label>`provides a usability improvement for mouse users in that when properly bound to the `<input>` it will toggle the `<input>`. Basically it gives mouse users a bigger target to hit. Eg they can click the `<label>` in addition to the `<input>` or control to give it focus.